# Add a new review queue for Random Posts

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Would it make sense to add a Random Posts review queue? This queue would basically work something like the following:

1. No badges earned for doing reviews, but you have a counter that tells you how many posts you have reviewed so far.
2. No limit to the number of posts you can review per day (Not too sure about this point).
3. Posts selected are random, but don't include things that are already part of other review queues and also exclude any post with more than 5 net upvotes.
4. If a post has been reviewed by someone, it does not show up again in this queue for something like 2 years.
5. A user needs something like 500 rep to use this queue.

There are probably a lot of users (Including myself) who would like to clean up the site and just don't know where to start. I understand that you could just do this yourself without using a review queue, but I would think it could be useful because:

1. If you want to do this yourself, you would have to build something outside the system like using [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries). This queue would provide an easy structured way to work systematically through posts.
2. You can only do 20 reviews per day for things like First Posts and most of the time, those queues are empty, so it can be frustrating trying to get something to review.
3. Different users using this queue don't get served the same posts, so less duplication of effort.
4. This would give users more practice before they get access to the Low Quality Posts and other queues.

Answer (score 14):

A random review queue like this is most likely going to result in a *lot* of invalid flags:

> "This post must've been selected for *some* reason, better flag it to be sure!"

<sup>(Not saying that that's proper review behaviour)</sup>

Besides, I imagine the majority of what's posted on SO (And hasn't been downvoted / deleted) to be, at very least, "Okay". Randomly selecting posts for review seems very inefficient...

I really don't see the benefit of adding such an feature.